# How to check if members having a particular role are present in a particular voice channel in discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to find if any member having a particular role id is present in a particular **voice channel**. If even 1 member having the particular role id is present in that particular voice channel, then only those members can use the commands of music bot.
From my research, I have came to know that `voiceStateUpdate` may help but the problem is I don't know how to use it in my codes(cause I am new to JavaScript). Here is the link to the documentation:
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-voiceStateUpdate .
Here is a part of my code:

```
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
  });
client.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return

    let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
    let cmd = messageArray[0];
    const args = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(' ');
    const searchString = args.slice(1).join(' ')
    const url = args[1] ? args[1].replace(/<(._)>/g, '$1') : ''
    const serverQueue = queue.get(message.guild.id)
   
 if() {        //the conditional statement I am trying to put here but I don't know how to do it properly
    if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}play`)) {
        const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel
        if (!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send("You need to be in a voice channel to play music")
    .......
```

So the main thing is that I don't know what to write their exactly in the if statement that would make my code work properly.

Answer (score 1):

```js
client.on("message", async message => {
    // Checking if the message author is a bot.
    if (message.author.bot) return false;
    // Checking if the message was sent in a DM channel.
    if (!message.guild) return false;

    // The role that can use the command.
    const Role = message.guild.roles.cache.get("RoleID");
    // The voice channel in which the command can be used.
    const VoiceChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.get("VoiceChannelID");

    if (message.content.toLowerCase() == "test") {
        // Checking if the GuildMember is in a VoiceChannel.
        if (!message.member.voice.channel) return message.reply("You need to be in a voice channel.");
        // Checking if the GuildMember is in the required VoiceChannel.
        if (message.member.voice.channelID !== VoiceChannel.id) return message.reply("You are in the wrong VoiceChannel.");
        // Checking if the GuildMember has the required Role.
        if (!message.member.roles.cache.has(Role.id)) return message.reply("You are not allowed to execute this command.");

        // Execute your command.
        return message.reply("Command executed");
    };
});
```

Comment: Thank You for replying. I want `if (!message.member.roles.cache.has(Role.id)) return message.reply("You are not allowed to execute this command.");` to be executed only when at least one member having the role is in that voice channel. If that member having the particular role isn't in that voice channel, then any members can use the command.

Comment: You can loop through the members of the `VoiceChannel` and check if any member has the role.

Answer (score 0):

So from what I can understand, you want the command to only execute when a user with the role 'Example Role' is in the channel 'Example Channel'

For this you will need the role id and the channel id.

```js
client.on("message", async message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (!(message.guild)) return;

    var roleID = 'RoleID';
    var vc = message.guild.channels.cache.get("VoiceChannelID");

    if (message.content.toLowerCase() == "test") {

        canUse = false;
        vc.members.forEach((member) => {
            if (member.roles.has(roleID)) {
                canUse = True;
            }
        })
        if (!(canUse)) { // nobody in the voice channel has the role specified.
            return;
        }
        console.log("A member of the voice channel has the role specified")
    }
});
```